# What is this Geis from?

Tags: fate-zero

On the Type-Moon Wikia entry for [Geis](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Geas#Geis) it says this:

> Contract used by Kiritsugu Emiya 
>   Binding magecraft: Target – Kiritsugu Emiya 
>   The Crests of the Emiya family hereby command: Provided that the following conditions are met, this oath shall become a commandment and bind the target without exception. 
>    
>   Oath: 
>   To the fifth head of the Emiya house, Kiritsugu, son of Noritaka: regarding both Kayneth Archibald El-Melloi and Sola-Ui Nuada-Re Sophia-Ri, all intentions and actions to kill and harm shall be forbidden for all eternity. 
>    
>   Conditions: 
>   Use up all the Command Seals, and let the Servant finish himself.

Now I've only seen up to Episode 10 but from how this reads it seems to have been in place before even the first fight between Saber and Lancer since by episode 10

> Sola-Ui Nuada-Re Sophia-Ri is Lancer's Master and probably doesn't care about Kayneth since she loves Lancer

However, Kiritsugu had tried to kill Kayneth on more than one occasion and there seems to be nothing that tries to stop him from breaking this Geis. in Fate/Stay Night in one of Heaven's Feel's bad endings, it's shown what happens when Shirou goes against the Geis he forms with Rin

> Once he plans on going against Rin's wishes of killing Sakura Matou, he finds that he cannot move his body at all to stop her. He is immediately freed upon Sakura's death, as there is no longer any reason to bind him.

and in Cú Chulainn's legend, his demise was caused when he was put in a situation where he had to break a Geis

- Never refuse a meal offered by a woman
- Never eat dog meat

He was offered a meal of dog meat by a woman and as such he had to break one Geis.

So while I may be jumping the gun here and asking this before watching the entire series, where does this Geis with Kiritsugu and Kayneth appear? If it was before the first fight between Saber and Lancer, how come there was nothing enforcing the Geis as there was with Shirou?

Comment: You're jumping the gun. Watch the entire series.

Comment: @senshin so the geis is actually made later in the series?

Comment: Yes, later in the series. You might want to avoid reading the wikia so much - you're just spoiling yourself for future plot points.

Comment: @senshin i try and avoid Fate/Zero elements since alot of TYPE-MOON Works i have to hope get translated and localized so i can't just avoid the wikia until the work i want to read up on is released (hope for a Fate/Extra CCC localization seems to be almost dead). i already know the gist of Fate/Zero anyway from other works, Saber dislikes Kiritsugu because of his actions, Sakura isn't saved by her uncle, Waver is "forced" into service by Reines in a similar matter as how he does in Fate/Apocrypha and i had already read up on Geis before Fate/Zero's anime was released

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spoilers for the second half of Fate/Zero:

> After the defeat of Caster in episode 15, Kayneth goes to the church (in episode 16) and asks Kirei's dad for a Command Spell as a reward for having helped defeat Caster (not that he did a damn thing; that was all Lancer). Kirei's dad agrees and gives him a Command Spell. At more or less the same time, Maiya abducts Sola-Ui and also cuts off her arm with the Command Spells. Lancer returns to Kayneth at this point, no longer able to locate Sola-Ui now that her Command Spells have been severed.
>
>  Saber (with Irisviel) happens upon Lancer at this point and they start dueling. Meanwhile, a bit away from the duel, Kiritsugu shows up with Sola-Ui's body and proposes a geis to Kayneth - Kiritsugu will leave Sola-Ui with Kayneth and shall nevermore harm either of them, provided that Kayneth uses up all his Command Spells and orders Lancer to commit suicide. Kayneth agrees, since that appears to be the only way out of the situation, and compels Lancer to kill himself. Kayneth breathes a sigh of relief, since he and Sola-Ui are now safe from Kiritsugu and Saber.
>
>  Of course, Maiya is lying in wait with a sniper rifle, and kills Kayneth and Sola-Ui immediately thereafter. She wasn't bound by the geis, after all. Sucks to be Kayneth.
>
>  In any case, only a few minutes at most pass between the geis taking effect and Kayneth/Sola-Ui being assassinated by Maiya (which renders the geis moot). The geis emphatically *was not* in effect at any time before that, and as such did not impact Kiritsugu/Saber's previous fights with Kayneth/Lancer.